# can I have the view in the front-end?

Tags: node.js, webpack, frontend

Here's my goal: having the views folder in the front end. I've been working with Node and Express a little and it's great that I can work on my views straight in the backend. But what if I wanted to just set my routes from express? I still want to keep the full power of templating and I want the front-end to be reusable and organized. So I can use Webpack to bundle a few components in a view, got that figured out. Question is, how do I do that for a few pages for which I have routes from the back-end? Do I just make different bundles for each?
Thanks for the tips!

Comment: This question doesn't seem quite clear to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to actually write two apps:

- A [RESTful web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).
- A client that consumes it.

Your Express app could consist only of RESTful endpoints. That means a route, something like `/api/articles`, that you can send `GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` requests to. These endpoints respond with `JSON` data and have no views.

Your client application could be a React, Vue.js, Angular, or whatever framework you're comfortable with, that consumes these web services of yours. All these frontend frameworks and libraries have support for templating engines like [Pug](https://pugjs.org/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

You won't need to create separate bundles for each part of your application. You can use a router library like [Vue Router](http://router.vuejs.org/en/) for Vue.js, or [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) for, well, ReactJS.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the insight! That is what I have in mind, connecting the front end to a REST API. However, I wanted to achieve that, not with a framework, but with just moving the Views folder from the back-end MVC to the front-end, in the scenario where the front-end developer would have to deliver a ready to be connected product (ex: the public folder). So I don't want a SPA but multiple pages from which I would make AJAX calls to the API. Achieved this from folder structure(which enabled some sort of natural routing) and a webpack config with multiple entry points and outputs.

Comment: @RaduMiron yeah, the approach would be basically the same except without the client-side router. If you want your frontend developer to build several pages, then you'll probably need a bundle for each.